# Stackmob is giving 401 error while registering device

Tags: stackmob

I am registering the device to stackmob with username and device token . I am getting valid tokens from c2dn and then storing it into db for that user and then while registering to stackmob i am using these parameters. On dev environment its working fine but same piece of code is giving 401 while registering the device. Please suggest me in this.

The  code for this is below :

```
public String registerWithNotificationServiceProvider(final String userName, final String deviceToken)        throws UserException 

         {
    if (userName.isEmpty() || deviceToken.isEmpty()) {
        throw new UserException(ResponseCodes.STATUS_BAD_REQUEST, "User Name or device      token is null",## Heading ##                    "label.invalid.user.device.details");
    }
    StackMobRequestSendResult deviceRegisterResult = null;
    deviceRegisterResult = StackMob.getStackMob().registerForPushWithUser(userName, deviceToken,
            new StackMobRawCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(HttpVerb requestVerb, String requestURL,
                        List<Map.Entry<String, String>> requestHeaders, String requestBody,
                        Integer responseStatusCode, List<Map.Entry<String, String>> responseHeaders,
                        byte[] responseBody) {
                    String response = new String(responseBody);
                    logger.info("request Body is " + requestBody);
                    logger.info("request Url is " + requestURL);
                    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : requestHeaders){
                        logger.info("Request Header is " + entry.getKey());
                        logger.info("Request Header content is " + entry.getValue());
                    }
                    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : responseHeaders){
                        logger.info("Response Header is " + entry.getKey());
                        logger.info("Response Header content is " + entry.getValue());
                    }
                    logger.info("response while  registering the device is  " + response);
                    logger.info("responseCode while registering device " + responseStatusCode);
                }
            });
    String status = null;
    if (deviceRegisterResult.getStatus() != null) {
        status = deviceRegisterResult.getStatus().name();
        logger.debug("For user : " + userName + " Status for registering device is " + status);
    }
    if (Status.SENT.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(status)) {
        return Status.SUCCESS.getStatus();
    } else {
        return Status.FAILURE.getStatus();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you setup your StackMob object with the api key and secret, do you remember to use apiVersion 1 with your production key and secret? That's the most likely problem.

```
StackMobCommon.API_KEY = KEY;
StackMobCommon.API_SECRET = SECRET;
StackMobCommon.USER_OBJECT_NAME = "user";
StackMobCommon.API_VERSION = 1; //! 0 for dev, 1 for production
```

If that doesn't work also set
    StackMob.getStackMob().getLogger().setLogging(true);
at the beginning and post the resulting logs

Comment: Actually I already answered this question in a support ticket. It turned out to be a problem where the local time was way off and oauth timestamp checks were failing. Newer versions of the sdk make an effort to keep the timestamping in sync with the server, so updating the sdk fixes the problem